# How do I access mobile data usage stats in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to programmatically access the mobile data usage in android?

A user can access the information using `Settings > Data Usage`

Answer (score 0):

In short, you just can get the NetworkInfo that not provide much information about user preferences (really none!). Just provide informations about network and e.g. mobile network provider.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html